# Defining form action from controller in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to define the action attribute of a form from the controller.

This is in my controller class:

```
model.addAttribute("action", "/signUnique(uClass=" + uClass + ")");
```

uClass is a string containing the value I want to pass in the url.
And this is in my html (thymeleaf) file:

```
<form th:action="@{${action}}" method="POST">
```

I'm getting this in the action:

```
/signUnique(uClass=2)
```

I'm new in thymeleaf and spring boot, and it is also my first time posting in stackoverflow, so please forgive me if I did something wrong.
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you just build the entire url in your controller:

```
model.addAttribute("action", "/signUnique?uClass=" + uClass);
```

If you really do want to parse a Thymeleaf expression in your template, you'll need to use [preprocessing](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing).  Something like this will work:

```
<form th:action="@{__${action}__}" method="POST">
```